# angular-moment-picker all dates disabled

Tags: angularjs

I am using a simple date picker: https://indrimuska.github.io/angular-moment-picker/ to allow a user to pick a date and time, but as you can see if you click "select a date" on my page all of the dates are disabled for some reason: http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/#/petType. I am not getting any errors so I don't know what the problem could be. I haven't changed anything in this view's controller except for adding in the default code given on the website in a .config and injecting into the module declaration.

```
.config(['momentPickerProvider', function (momentPickerProvider) {
    momentPickerProvider.options({
        /* Picker properties */
        locale:        'en',
        format:        'L LTS',
        minView:       'decade',
        maxView:       'minute',
        startView:     'year',
        autoclose:     true,
        today:         false,
        keyboard:      false,
        disable: false,

        /* Extra: Views properties */
        leftArrow:     '&larr;',
        rightArrow:    '&rarr;',
        yearsFormat:   'YYYY',
        monthsFormat:  'MMM',
        daysFormat:    'D',
        hoursFormat:   'HH:[00]',
        minutesFormat: moment.localeData().longDateFormat('LT').replace(/[aA]/, ''),
        secondsFormat: 'ss',
        minutesStep:   5,
        secondsStep:   1
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved in the [v0.6.7](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker/releases/tag/0.6.7) release of the directive.